# ошибка Ни одна транзакция не была ранее начата

Tags: mysql, база-данных, транзакции

НЕ пойму почему не работает ROLLBACK. Использую опенсервер, база данных mysql, тип таблицы InnoDB.
Я начинаю транзакцию START TRANSACTION; В документации сказано, что стоит режим autocommit. Я отключаю его с помощью SET AUTOCOMMIT=0. Сама таблица максимально простая, 3 поля (id, name, age). Пишу запросы:

```
UPDATE test1 SET age= 55 WHERE id = '1';
UPDATE test1 SET age= 55 WHERE id = '2';
```

Они выполняются. Но в итоге при написании ROLLBACK OR COMMIT ошибка вида:"Ни одна транзакция не была ранее начата".

Comment: Чтобы завершить или откатить транзакцию, её надо как минимум начать...

Comment: @Akina Я исправила ответ, и с использованием START TRANSACTION; (до этого использовала BEGIN) - результат тот же.

Comment: Приведите ПОЛНЫЙ код. DDL таблицы, тестовое наполнение, код процедуры с транзакцией - чтобы можно было воспроизвести Вашу ситуацию. Ещё лучше - сразу сделайте fiddle.